# In practice what is (modified) Gram Schmidt used for?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Modified Gram-Schmidt is known to be numerically less stable than methods like Householder orthogonalization and also not quite as fast at approximately $2mn^2$ flops. So in practice do we ever use it, or is it simply a nice theoretical excercise?

Comment: Gram Schmidt provides an orthogonal basis for the span of the $k$ first vectors for every $k \le m$

Comment: I see, so if you ever wanted a partial basis it would have a role. This seems useful, does anyone have examples of where this is used in practice?